# Get array elements by internal value

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$a = [
    0 => ['a' => ['id' => 10, 'value' => 111]],
    1 => ['a' => ['id' => 20, 'value' => 222]],
    2 => ['a' => ['id' => 30, 'value' => 333]]
];
```

I want to use this array inside `array_filter()` to filter `$ids`comparing the `value`:

```
$ids = [10, 20, 30];
$filtered = array_filter($ids, function($id) use($a) {
    return $a[$id][$value] == 222; //this is wrong, just to show what I'm trying
});
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Start with `var_dump($id)` inside a callback and see it's structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. What do you want to filter?

All elements from `$ids`  which are in `$a` with `value` 222?

Then do this:

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($a as $item) {
    if ($item['a']['value'] == 222)
        $ids[] = $item['a']['id'];
}
```

**Update**: `array_filter` returns full item of array, it means that it doesn't return just `id`:

```
$ids = array_filter($a, function($v) { return $v['a']['value'] == 222; } );
```

Comment: Yeah, That's what I want to do, but I would like to use `array_filter`... but I think that there's no way of doing this using `array_filter`.

Comment: Updated, but `array_filter` will do a part of job.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, `$a` does not have 10, 20, 30 keys but 0, 1, 2. When you use `$a[$id]` inside the closure, it iterates for `$a[10]`, `$a[20]`, `$a[30]` (which do not exist).

If you want to filter `$a`, then put `$a` as the first parameter of array_filter. You use `$ids` as the first parameter and it does not iterature for `$a`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i dont get why u need $ids array. Guys said correct, you should walk $a array and the code will be

```
    $filtered = array_filter($a, function($item) {
        return $item['a']['value'] == 222; 
    });
```